# fadeIn issues with with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, scrolltop

I'm trying to have my content fade in when reaching a certain proximity to to respective ends of the page. The fade works fine when the trigger is set to the very top and bottom but when I set a distance (200px) the fade no longer works and the content simply appears.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()<=200){
            $('#about .content').stop(true,true).fadeIn("5s");
        } 
        else {
            $('#about .content').stop(true,true).fadeOut("10s");
        }

     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 200) {
            $('#work .content').stop(true,true).fadeIn("5s");
        } else {
            $('#work .content').stop(true,true).fadeOut("5s");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you have two functions working against each other:

The first function has an "if-else" statement and the second function as well.
That means that each function does something EVERYTIME you scroll.
There are multiple ways of solving this.

The way I would solve it is using a variable and updating the constraints.

Let's say we have a variable onScreen that has value 1 if the paragraph is on the screen and value 0 if it isn't:

For example:

```
<div style="height: 800px">Example of scroll with fadeIn, fadeOut.

<p style="margin-top:300px;">These paragraphs will go away when you have scrolled
 more than 10 pixels from the top. They will appear again when you have scrolled 
to a proximity of 50 pixels from the bottom. They will also appear if you go 
within a proximity of 10 pixels of the top again.</p>

</div>
```

Now for the jQuery code:

```
var $onScreen = 1;

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() < 10){
      if ($onScreen == 0)
      {
        $("p:first").stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow", "linear");
        $onScreen = 1;  
      }
    }   

if($(window).scrollTop() <= 20 && $(window).scrollTop() >= 10){
      if ($onScreen == 1)
      {
        $("p:first").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow", "linear");
        $onScreen = 0;  
      }
    } 

 if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 50) {
     if ($onScreen == 0)
     {
         $("p:first").stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow", "linear");
         $onScreen = 1;
     }
    }
 });
```

Now this is not the most concise way of doing it and I didn't mean to do so: by making the code a bit more extensive I hope you can follow why it works now and didn't work before (such that you actually learn from it).

I prepared a live example for you on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ycCAb/4/

I hope this answers your question. Good luck!

Comment: Note that I made the example in such a way that quick scrolling is not allowed. So grab the scrollbar and slowly move it down to see the functions execute. For your usage: change the parameters of the fadeOut function to allow for quick scrolling (because currently it only has a margin of 10px). Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the help!

Is it somehow possible to have the contents opacity dependent on the proximity to the top/bottom so that instead of one point being a trigger for the fade, it will only be at full opacity when you're all the way scrolled up/down and will have a range based on your position?

Comment: Everything is possible with code :) You still need help on the opacity problem? Or you got that as well?

Comment: hahah well you are right on that one
Yeah I've posted a new question with my new concerns if you want to check it out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849002/opacity-of-content-relative-to-scroll-position-issues

Comment: I will have a go at it tomorrow. (It's evening here)